# convert scalefactor to percentage value

Tags: android, zooming

Hi I have implemented pinch to zoom functionality in my app. Now i am getting zoom value as float. But i have to send this to server as a percentage value. If it is zoom in positive integer from 1-100.if it is zoom out negative integer from 0--100. Given below is my code. How can i convert that?

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
  SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
  @Override
  public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
   scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
   scale = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(scale, 10.0f));

   if( detector.getScaleFactor()<1.0f)
      isZoomed=false;
   else
      isZoomed=true;
  return true;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 100 to convert a number into a percent

but these guys want 0 as full size, so substract one first

```
 result = ( scaleFactor -1 ) * 100 ;
```

with a maximum scalefactor of 10 that'll get you a number between -100 and +900 
they want -100 to +100 so you should limit scalefactor to a maximum of 2.

Comment: getting some weired values :(